# A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Private key was in an unrecognized format

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to setup an SSL on AWS coudfront, but have this error, `A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Private key was in an unrecognized` format., when running the following command:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name domain.tld --certificate-body file:///home/khine/certs/14595113.crt --private-key file:///home/khine/certs/domain.key --certificate-chain file:///home/khine/Sandboxes/Business/certs/domain.tld.bundle.crt --path /cloudfront/domain.tld/
```

this is how i setup got my files:

```
openssl ecparam -out domain.key -name secp384r1 -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key doamin.key -nodes -out domain.tld_ssl.csr
```

then i user the csr file created to get the certificate for my domain.

i got the following files back:

```
root@www:/etc/ssl/certs # ls
14595113.crt
COMODOECCExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODOECCAddTrustCA.crt
domain.tld.bundle.crt
```

From https://rasmith.me.uk/2014/07/27/So-You-Want-To-Be-Secure/

The three files stipulated are;

- Your server certificate in PEM format.
- Your private key in PEM format.
- A certificate chain file.

When I try to convert my key to PEM format, I get the following error:

```
# openssl rsa -in domain.key -outform PEM -out domain_pem.key
34379118248:error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA:expecting an rsa key:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/evp/p_lib.c:288:
```

Google returns this http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/EVP-PKEY-get1-RSA-expecting-an-rsa-key-td46677.html

but no one has answered it.

Any advise on how I can convert the key to PEM format, or if I have missed something in my procedure will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove **EC PARAMETERS** section from private key file

Your key needs to have header **-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----**

and footer **-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----**

Just remove first three lines from key file

Answer (score -2):

For those who believe their certificates are correct and still facing this issue, browse to a location where certificates (PEM encoded) are presents and then try to upload:

`aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name enterprise-dev-iflb --certificate-body file://iflb-public-key.pem --private-key file://iflb-no-path-phrase-key.pem`

Answer (score -2):

I was getting the same error. It turns out that the way i was generating my private key, from a `p12` keystore, was not correct. Then i use this command (to export unencrypted private key):

`openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out cert.pem`

and my command was successful.

`aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name elastic-beanstalk-x509 --certificate-body file://cert.crt --private-key file://cert.pem`